# INSERT query in sqlite working in browser,but not in android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

i have been really spendin a lot of time on this code but i am not able to any reason why database is not working

I want to insert just one row.So I created this func:

void insertfav(String k) {

```
    myDataBase = khol();
    Cursor cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT " + colname + " from "
            + deptTable + " WHERE " + col3 + "=" + "'" + k + "'",
            new String[] {});
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String area = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(colname));
    cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT " + col2 + " from " + deptTable
            + " WHERE " + col3 + "=" + "'" + k + "'", new String[] {});
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String disease = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(col2));
    myDataBase.rawQuery(
            "INSERT INTO " + favtable + " ("+colname+", "+col2+", "+col3+")"
                    + "Values (" + "'" + area + "'" + ", " + "'" + disease
                    + "'" + ", " + "'" + k + "'" + ")", new String[] {});
    myDataBase.close();
}
```

This query is working fine when I run it in the sqlite browser but when this function is actually called while running the app in emulator, nothing gets inserted.

khol() is a function which opens the database.This is the code of khol() func:

```
public SQLiteDatabase khol() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    return myDataBase;
}
```

where DB_PATH and DB_NAME are:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/example.SQLitetest/";

private static String DB_NAME = "desicures.db";
```

although khol() is working properly in other queries but might be i am doing something wrong here...

Plz help me out...

Comment: Do you have any idea which part of the query isn't working? Could you trace out the generated SQL perhaps?

Comment: also.. do you see some errors in the logcat?

Comment: the INSERT INTO query is not inserting the data into database..

Comment: @Ovidiu Latcu..There are no errors in logcat

Comment: @user182022 : try to use `execSQL` instead of `rawQuery`

Comment: Start by watching the value the SQL you're actually running. In a debugger or with window.alert(). It's probably malformed by the value of one or more parameter strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things about your code

- execSQL instead of rawQuery
- use `?` and params in the `String[]` - that's safer and can handle `k = "ha'ck"`
- be nice and close Cursors

Like about so:

```java
myDataBase = khol();
Cursor cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT " + colname + " from "
        + deptTable + " WHERE " + col3 + "=?",
        new String[] { k });
cur.moveToFirst();
String area = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(colname));
cur.close();
cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT " + col2 + " from " + deptTable
        + " WHERE " + col3 + "=?", new String[] { k });
cur.moveToFirst();
String disease = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(col2));
cur.close();

// either
myDataBase.execSQL(
        "INSERT INTO " + favtable + " ("+colname+", "+col2+", "+col3+")"
                + "Values (?, ?, ?)",
                new String[] { area, disease, k });
// or 
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(colname, area);
cv.put(col2, disease);
cv.put(col3, k);
long newRowId = myDataBase.insert(favtable, colname, cv);

myDataBase.close();
```

And in addition you might need to check if Cursors are `null` / contain values. `cur.getString` could either give you a `NullPointerException` or an error because there is no Column (if your db has no data).

Also your query should not need multiple queries, you can request multiple columns at once:

```
cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT " + colname + "," + col2 + " from "
        + deptTable + " WHERE " + col3 + "=?", new String[] { k, k });
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    // starting at 0 columns are ordered in the way you select them
    String area = cur.getString(0);
    String disease = cur.getString(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try using [myDatabase.insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) instead of rawQuery.

Answer (score 1):

as [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) says about  `rawQuery`:

```
Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.
```

and for `execSQL(String sql)` :

```
Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement 
that returns data.

    Execute a single SQL statement that is not a query. For example, CREATE TABLE, 
DELETE,INSERT, etc. Multiple statements separated by ;s are not supported. it takes a 
write lock
```

try to use execSQL instead of rawQuery.like

```
myDataBase.execSQL(
            "INSERT INTO " + favtable + " ("+colname+", "+col2+", "+col3+")"
                    + "Values (" + "'" + area + "'" + ", " + "'" + disease
                    + "'" + ", " + "'" + k + "'" + ");");
```

Comment: coz Chintan answered first. it was his solution that solved my problem first..and i thought i can accept more than one answer..that's why only..i am sorry..

Comment: it's ok but see my comment time on your question and @Chintan answer?

Comment: at that time i selected Chintan's answer coz he even explained the other method but your answer on how i can implement execSQL came later..hey i will post one another ques..and will select your answer if it will be the best irrespective of time constraint..no hard feelings mate..

Comment: ko done im waiting.. but my comment come first from all answers so plz always response to comments when anyone give to your question..

Answer (score 0):

the method rawQuery() returns cursor, you can not make insert using this method, so

```
myDataBase.rawQuery(
        "INSERT INTO " + favtable + " ("+colname+", "+col2+", "+col3+")"
                + "Values (" + "'" + area + "'" + ", " + "'" + disease
                + "'" + ", " + "'" + k + "'" + ")", new String[] {});
```

is wrong method.

you can use the insert() method, you can try followin

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(colname , area);
values.put(col2 , disease);
values.put(col3 , k);
long rowID = db.insert(favtable, null, values);
System.out.println("Added Row No: "+rowID);
```